# Excel VBA - Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True in Workbook_close does nothing

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I've spent days looking everywhere, it seems an Excel bug dating back 15 years.

In a workbook I have

```
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
```

I'd like to turn it on when closing the file, but nothing works.

I put

```
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
```

in both

```
Private Sub Workbook_close(Cancel As Boolean)
```

and in

```
Private Sub Workbook_beforeclose(Cancel As Boolean)
```

Nothing, the formula bar won't appear when opening a new Excel file.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue. works fine for me in office 365 32 bit

Comment: I have Excel 2010 at work and Excel 2019 at home, and I have this issue.